# Use UrlFetchApp service to get data from remote server (IBM Clearquest)

Tags: google-apps-script, httprequest, clearquest

I shall put my requirement first.
**I need to get query data from IBM rational clearquest web server using google apps script.**

**Solution I found:**
I have googled and found that a Rest URI can be created in Clearquest for running a query. I have created that and got an URL.
Now using UrlFetchApp.fetch(url). I am trying to get the data.
But I am facing **DNS Error**.
What can be the reason?
Please let me know the fix and any new solutions are also accepted.

```html
function testingURLFetchApp(){


  var url = "htp://prs02613:12080/cqweb/restapi/8.0.0/NGI/QUERY/Personal%20Queries/Defect%20Query?format=HTML&loginId={{loginid}}&password={{password}}&noframes=true";
    try{    
    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      

    } catch(err) {
      Logger.log("ERROR: " + err);
    }
  
}
```

I used snippet because I was not able to place it in code tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrongly mentioned "htp://". Double change the URL and try again.

Comment: Hi, I deliberately entered it as htp as stackoverflow was not accepting http as a code. Sorry forgot to mention it